# Marginal effects for coefficients of a beta regression

Tags: r, regression, beta, coefficients, marginal-effects

I am fitting a beta regression using the `betareg` function in R.
I would like to use a function like `effect` or `margins` to compute the marginal effects of the coefficients.
However none of both of them actually work with this kind of model.

Does anybody know a function that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `vignette("supported_models", package = "marginaleffects")`, the [marginaleffects package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=marginaleffects) fully supports `betareg` models.

```
                                Numerical equivalence
Supported by marginaleffects    Stata     margins   emtrends
Package     Function            dY/dX SE  dY/dX SE  dY/dX SE
...
betareg     betareg               ✓    ✓    ✓    ✓    ✓   ✓
```

However, this table *also* says that `betareg` models are supported by `margins::margins()` and `emmeans::emtrends()`.  Can you please give us a minimal reproducible example that shows the data and model you're fitting, and also shows the results you would want (e.g. by fitting an equivalent `lm()` to the same data)?